# How to animate a spritesheet without an atlas?

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have a sprite sheet for about 30 frames of different animations that are not in order.

I would like to use Starling to make the animations but I do not have / don't have the time to make a atlas xml. Even if I did, I would rather NOT use the atlas.

Furthermore, the sprite sheet has a black background and most examples I researched have transparent background.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are the images the same size ?

Comment: @Binou Yes. All images have the same frameW and frameH of 80 / 105.

Comment: you can try [ShoeBox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/), it can extract the images from the sprite sheet. After that you can renames the images in the good order and repack them and generate the xml. I think it's the better/faster solution. Without an xml you have to hardcode the images positions has they are not in the good order in the sprite sheet, it's boring to do and a very bad way of programming ;)

Comment: @Binou I saw a loose comment somewhere about using something like addAnimation("frame_", [0,1,2], 30) where 0, 1, 2 are the index of the frames in the spritesheet. One would assume he defines how big a frame is and Starling extracts those pieces. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: yes sure it's possible to do something like this but i think it's much better to make an atlas.xml.

Comment: @Binou I understand, but even so, please provide me with the way without the xml as an Answer to the question. Also what about that black background?

Comment: for the black background you can use photoshop or gimp to remove the black from the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to retrieve the textures from the atlas giving the frames you want and the frames width and height:

```
package
{
    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class AnimFromAtlas
    {
        public function AnimFromAtlas( )
        {

        }

        public static function TexturesFromAtlas( atlas:Texture, frames:Array, frameWidth:int, frameHeight:int ):Vector.<Texture>
        {
            // declare x and y properties 
            var x:int, y:int = 0;
            // create the base rectangle with the flrame width and frame height, we just have to update the x and y values.
            var region:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight );
            // create the texture vector that we have to return
            var textures:Vector.<Texture> = new <Texture>[];
            // calculate the max frame on one line on the atlas
            var framesOnLine:int = atlas.width / frameWidth;

            // loop the frames to get the textures on the atlas
            for( var i:int = 0; i<frames.length; ++i )
            {
                x = (int( (frames[i] % framesOnLine) ) * frameWidth);   
                y = (int( (frames[i] / framesOnLine) ) * frameHeight);
                region.x = x;
                region.y = y;
                textures[i] = Texture.fromTexture(atlas, region);

                trace( region );
            }

            // fix the vector for better performances
            textures.fixed = true;

            // return the textures
            return textures;
        }
    }
}
```

So you just have to call the static method `AnimFromAtlas.TexturesFromAtlas(yourSpriteSheet, [1,2,5,8,3], 150, 100);`

If you have your atlas as Bitmap and not as Texture you can use `Texture.fromBitmap(yourBitmap)` to get the Texture.

I didn't tried it so maybe it don't work as you want but i think it should do the trick, i added a trace of the rectangles found for the textures so you can see if it seems credible or not.

for the black background, you can do it directly with as3 like this:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = yourAtlasBitmap.bitmapData;
var black     :uint = 0xff000000;  // the black color to replace
var trans     :uint = 0x00000000;  // the transparent color that will replace the black
var mask      :uint = 0xffffffff;  // the mask to use (i always use white here)
// the target rectangle
var rect      :Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height );

// do the replacement of the color
bitmapData.threshold( bitmapData, rect, new Point(0,0), "==", black, trans, mask, true );

// create a new Bitmap with the new BitmapData
var yourNewBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

I hope this could help you.